# User answers a question of another user and asks the same question again already answered by himself; how to handle this post?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, etiquette, plagiarism

The following question was answered by the user [makboney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358121/makboney):

- [Siri - stop call initiating if contact is not in the application's contact list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436004/siri-stop-call-initiating-if-contact-is-not-in-the-applications-contact-list)

The same user then posted a new question with the same content of the question he had already answered, but with a different title:

- [Siri - contact searching behaviour similar to skype for audio call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462179/siri-process-to-handle-confirmstartaudiocall)

How to handle this post?

Currently flagged as duplicate, so can't use **in need of moderator intervention** flag.

Edit: Also raised moderator flag as duplicate flag approved.

Comment: That user looks very suspicious indeed. Good call.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

OK, maybe I'm just in a really good mood today because it's my birthday but this has got to be one of the most entertaining cases I've handled yet. That user either has a really eccentric memory (remembering only the question he answered and not his answer), or doesn't realize he can answer his own question and is, well, trying to figure out how. Totally not trying to use sock puppets to cheat the system at all, nope.

So I helped him out a little by deleting his sock puppet and merging his answer into his question so it becomes a self-answered question under his own account.

---

I should add though that this sort of thing doesn't *always* point to sock puppet activity. There have been cases of users reposting existing questions verbatim while not actually being related to the original posters at all.

Why on earth would they do that, then? The world may never know. But you should still flag for them to be closed as duplicates, and possibly alert a moderator. Because a word-for-word copy of a question is never normal under any circumstances.

Comment: I also sent him a warning, in case he *was* trying to cheat the system. Just in case.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks and doing great things on birthday is really great!..HBD@BoltClock

Comment: @BoltClock bdw Happy Birth Day :)

Comment: Should everyone congratulate you or is it sufficient to upvote the existing congratulatory comments? (=

Comment: @Hermann Pollute the comment thread underneath a moderator's answer with irrelevant repetitive comments that have no relation to the problem at hand? Yes, we should do that. Congratz BoltClock! You are now one year older than you were previously.

Comment: @BoltClock Wish You A Many More Happy Returns of the Day!!! Have a Blast!!! ☺ Happy New Year Wishes!!! 

Comment: Happy Birthday Day BoltClock... beg your pardon. i asked the first question from my home with a new account since i forgot my credential of this account(makboney), i was doing some rnd. and after getting the answer next day i just posted it from office with my original account. I have no idea how it merged with my original account. i was trying to help the others. you know there is not much resource/help on community regarding audio calling using sirikit.

we all are here to help each other but continuous down voting demotivated such thing.

anyway it is my fault and happy new year to all

Comment: @makboney: That's why I said I helped you out by merging your answer to your question under your main account so it becomes a proper self-answered question. Your history isn't very promising, though, considering this isn't the first time you've used multiple accounts to ask, answer and vote for yourself, hence my email warning. But if this was indeed an honest mistake on your part I ask that you don't repeat it in the future. Using multiple accounts is generally not safe unless you can ensure that your accounts do not cross paths - because doing so is against the rules.

Comment: @BoltClock thank you for reply, but i am not sure what history you are talking about. this is the first time i used multiple accounts and i made it clear about the purpose. I will try not to repeat it again.

Comment: @JDB Nope. *Your history isn't very promising, though, considering **this isn't the first time you've used multiple accounts** to ask, answer and vote for yourself, hence my email warning.*

Comment: @BoltClock *Using multiple accounts is generally not safe unless you can ensure that your accounts do not cross paths* So owning multiple accounts is allowed as long as they don't interact?

Comment: @redesign ah... oops.

Comment: @Redesign http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange

Comment: @Redesign: Yes. See Tiny Giant's link.

Answer (score 6):

You did the correct thing, flag for moderator attention. From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered):

> If it looks like there is an egregious pattern of plagiarism, and deletions seem necessary, flag for moderator attention.

(that post talks about answers, but it still applies here).

If you can't raise a flag because there's another one pending, you can flag one of the other posts by that user.

Comment: Already flagged for moderator attention.