# Why aren't you asking more Questions?

Tags: discussion

Many of us seem quite unhappy with the scarcity of quality questions on the site.

If you're reading this, you're probably more than qualified to ask good questions.

If you are also unhappy with question scarcity, then...

***Why aren't you asking more questions?***

### Possible reasons

I'll speculate as to possible reasons (enumerated for ease of referencing):

1. Do you feel that you will lose face if you, probably an expert in some domain, ask a question that you don't know the answer to?
2. Do you feel that question reception is capricious or unfair?
3. Do you think you will face easy recrimination or revenge from users whose posts you or others have criticized, downvoted, and closed in the past?
4. Do you feel that it will simply take too long for you to write up a question that is considered "good"?
5. Do you just always know what you need to know (because of experience or you know how to research or read documentation) without asking someone else, so you don't see the point in asking?

(I expect to keep this open-ended, if more canonical reasons appear, I'll add them here.)

### My experience

Let me tell you why I don't ask very many questions. I feel question reception is frequently unprincipled and capricous. In fact I warn others when I talk about how to engage on this site to just avoid asking questions altogether, unless they're willing to risk the following sort of treatment.

I did a self Q&A here: [Python, what's the Enum type good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601644/python-whats-the-enum-type-good-for)

I was unable to find a dupe target, so I put some effort into writing up the question as well, keeping in mind the downvote mouseover text:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

So I attempted to ensure that I demonstrated that I did my homework, demonstrating the alternatives to Python's new Enum while not actually attempting to answer the question in the question.

### The drubbing

The question was almost immediately downvoted to net -7 or -8 (I don't recall exactly). Some of the commenters were unaware that you are encouraged to "Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)", and some were questioning my motives, saying things like:

> it's suspect, theres no way in hell he could type that in 60 seconds

and

> Probably because he posted this question, then proceeds to produce a fully cited and complete answer a minute later. Producing a self answer is fine, but doing it to gain rep doesn't seem to be within the spirit of the "self answer" rules.

One commenter seemed to think that information that might be available elsewhere 
shouldn't be here commented this on the answer:

> I get that the answer is fine and all, but I really don't think should be a question here. There is already a lot of information on the topic of enum in the form of blogs, other SO questions, python docs, tutorials, etc. Really no need for this

(logically obviating the need for the site altogether.)

Another said:

> The question itself seems long-winded and not particularly useful to me

To which I responded: "A common criticism of questions is that they demonstrate no knowledge or research, or that the asker did not do his homework, or show his work. I'm attempting to demonstrate all of the above." They replied:

> I see your point actually, guess I was a bit harsh..

But I don't recall an indication of a retracted downvote.

I then got three or more close votes as "primarily opinion based" for this reason:

> "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

I was befuddled by this close reason, because my answer had almost nothing but facts, demonstrations, and references.

### Evidence from elsewhere

But recent comments other users on a [different meta post of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350537/541136) said:

> There is an overwhelming community consensus that these [other] questions should not be allowed. So if there exists an explicit close reason or not is quite irrelevant, such questions should be closed. Mostly people pick "too broad" for closing them and that's fine.

and

> everyone just votes to close these ["gimme teh codez"] type of question with some random reason anyway, usually "too broad", even if they are not actually to broad. so i don't understand what SO is trying to accomplish by not giving us an accurate close reason. but then again, I don't understand much of what SO is trying to accomplish in general these days...

Both of these comments suggest unprincipled or dishonest application of close votes.

(Yes a dupe target for my example Q&A was eventually found, and that's totally fair, but that was more than an hour after I got that reception. No one was aware of a dupe target while they were excoriating my question.)

### My conclusion based on my experience

I feel that question reception could be improved.

At this point, I *might* risk asking more questions, but I pretty much refuse to ask questions without researching the answer myself and posting it with my question so that users who find my question difficult to answer don't look for excuses to close it without my own answer at least supporting the question's existence (or perhaps even standing as the canonical answer).

### You're not asking questions.

I recently interacted with several meta users, all who were unhappy with scarcity of questions with quality, all who seemed willing to bend the rules to shut down bad questions, and all whom had lots of answers (in the thousands), and very *very* few questions (in the tens or even none at all).

I'm concluding that there are many users who want more high quality questions. So why aren't they asking more questions?

### Recap and potential followup questions:

I sometimes get poor and unprincipled question reception, and that's why I don't ask very much. I suppose you think you will too, which is why you don't ask very much either.

Perhaps I'm wrong, so I'm asking ***you***,

***Why aren't you asking more Questions?***

And if I'm right, how can we improve question reception for established users?

Do we need a privilege that makes downvotes cost the voter on questions? (Like for every 10k rep you get to ask 1 "privileged" question per month.)

Or do we just need to improve our culture of welcoming questions from established users?

It would be a great boon to all of us to have a new population of really smart and experienced users asking questions here, right?

If you're reading this, you're probably really smart and part of that ideal population, but are you afraid to ask?

Comment: Asking questions for the sake of asking questions is asking for trouble. Realistically, the example here is beside the point and serves only to derail this discussion.

Comment: Self-answered questions (shouldn't be, but) are a whole different beast and don't really fit in with the rest of what you're talking about.

Comment: In the tags I frequent, there really are no good questions to be asked. They can almost all be answered by making an effort to do some research yourself. I've been on the site for years and have asked less than 20 questions. (Honestly, half of the ones I have asked are probably too specific to be of use to a wider audience! I do my best to make them useful to others though.)

Comment: Let's see: #1, #3, and any problems I've had recently being too particular to a specific project as opposed to being generally useful. (Ex: I had a problem getting Bootstrap tooltips to play nice with a paged table being populated by Knockout a while back.) I did ask a PL/SQL question once but the only thing I got was the Tumbleweed badge.

Comment: *I was befuddled by this close reason, because my answer had almost nothing but facts, demonstrations, and references.* - I'm not saying I agree with them but the "primarily opinion based" close votes were because of the question, not your answer.

Comment: @BSMP - please put your answer into an answer!

Comment: I think part of the reason may be something that's just inherent in the type of person who likes to answer questions. If they don't know the answer to a question, whether it's someone else's or their own, they prefer to search and experiment to find it rather than asking someone else for it. The fact that they've put a lot of time into practicing and developing their skill at this is what enables them to answer questions, but it also means they're less likely to even be interested in asking.

Comment: Of course, that doesn't really apply to self-answers like your example.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's a great point, but it probably belongs in an Answer. Nevertheless, perhaps I, for example, as an answerer at a huge ratio to questions, should take one for the team and put my excellence at composing posts to work writing questions to help me learn a new subject (like Haskell or some such language?)?

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't think it addressed the question completely enough to justify being an answer.

Comment: Well perhaps you should flesh out the idea a bit more then?

Comment: I will say while it hasn't affected my _asking_ questions, your #3 has certainly affected my voting on answers to my questions.  Especially when I need to down-vote, I fully anticipate some kind of recrimination.

Comment: `The question was almost immediately downvoted to net -7 or -8`. The timeline says otherwise... `Jun 2 '16 votes daily summary N/A Up: 9 Down: 8`

Comment: I appreciate your research, but the upvotes came almost all completely after the downvotes. Perhaps one or more was actually retracted and I didn't notice.

Comment: @AaronHall Perhaps, but it's somewhat misleading to say it was downvoted to -7 and omit the fact it was then immediately upvoted to +1. The question is now sitting at +3 with an answer of +20 *despite* it being a duplicate question (found within 24 hours). I don't really think this is a good example of the community being too hostile to questions.

Comment: I can appreciate how it looks to you. I hope you can appreciate how it looks to an the asker looking at a -5, -6, -7, -8 net score, with lots of specious alternative criticisms and votes to close. I guarantee you that *I* felt the reception was hostile. I have a fairly robust ego - if it affected me that way, how do you suppose it affects others?

Comment: "Producing a self answer is fine, but doing it to gain rep doesn't seem to be within the spirit of the 'self answer' rules." And this sort of attitude is why people resort to using sock puppets to do self-Q&As. (No, not really; I wager the majority of people who use sock puppets to self-answer do so simply because [they have no idea the self-answer feature even exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340839/user-answers-a-question-of-another-user-and-asks-the-same-question-again-already/340843#340843).)

Comment: i'm not afraid of criticism - I don't ask because I Google and I find my answer in previous questions on SO. About improving our culture of welcoming questions from established users - Sure, why not, but only if established users could handle newcomers asking LQ questions better - I’d be interested to know the reasons that made our community to, **apparently**, not being welcoming to questions anymore

Comment: Still sad that it happened to begin with of course, sounds like you were ganged up on. Lets hope the individuals work themselves into a form of a ban eventually.

Comment: Most of the time it's faster to just figure out how to solve my problem. Asking a question here is my very last resort because it's an asynchronous process that halts my workflow. I'd much rather solve my problem *now* rather than waiting for someone to eventually come up with an answer.

Comment: `I might risk asking more questions, but I pretty much refuse to ask questions without researching the answer myself` - [MISSION ACCOMPLISHED](https://xkcd.com/810/)!

Comment: I ask a question when I have a question, and don't ask a question when I don't have a question. It's not like I sit in front of my computer and say to myself, "OK now, let's figure out some question to ask".

Comment: I'm on probation...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't ask questions since by the time I distill the question to a "Stack Overflow" worthy question, it's normally not answerable in the sea of sand questions on SO.

So if I post it, I either:

- Waste time writing it up
- Self answer eventually
- Get misguided people posting crap or answers to it which straight up are irrelevant
- Have such a trivial question that it annoying me that I can't easily find the info so I ask it anyway

Which means I rarely do. Realistically I normally only post them to self-answer in the hopes I save some poor soul from [an encounter with DenverCoder9](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients).

When I have questions, I now ask in smaller close-knit chat based communities, which have become considerably better for addressing real, interesting, and non-trivial questions.

---

> Do you feel that you will lose face if you, probably an expert in some domain, ask a question that you don't know the answer to?

... not even close.

> Do you feel that question reception is capricious or unfair?

Sure, simple easy "fish in a barrel" questions worded well get far better reception than challenging, interesting, or difficult ones.

> Do you think you will face easy recrimination or revenge from users whose posts you or others have criticized, downvoted, and closed in the past?

I gave up caring about this a *loooonnnnng* time ago.

> Do you feel that it will simply take too long for you to write up a question that is considered "good"?

Not really. By the time I feel like even asking on SO I've done enough research to do that.

> Do you just always know what you need to know (because of experience or you know how to research or read documentation) without asking someone else, so you don't see the point in asking?

It's surprisingly easier to read the source code in many cases than it is to read documentation. And learning to find information is a necessity if you want to not suck at programming, which I have been getting better and better with as I get older.

Comment: #3 so much for me. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-excessively-for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/429774 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/449447 Even though I'm entirely capable of asking consistently on-topic and high-quality questions, I'm not motivated to not because they are poorly received, but because they are being enthusiastically received by the wrong people. Stack Overflow bills itself as a site to get answers from experts but really, how many experts do people think there are?

Comment: @BoltClock There must be a lot of experts because they get hired [all the time](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/01/27/news-58/) ....

Answer (score 27):

I don't ask many questions because I rarely hit a problem that cannot be answered by existing resources, being other Stack Overflow questions, vendor documentation (MSDN, GitHub, etc.) or trial and error.

In fact, several times I have come up with a solution while formulating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a question. So why didn't I post the question, then self answer with my solution? Because I feel that given the nature of what I'm working on most of my problems are too specific to be of any use to other users.

Never have I worried about "losing face" or getting downvoted and revenge downvoting as not once crossed my mind. I think for most people it comes down to parts of point 4 and 5: not having enough time to fully flesh out a good question, and knowing enough to be able to answer given existing resources.

I don't think experienced or high rep users should be treated any differently when it comes to asking or answering questions. High rep users can just as easily ask a bad question that should be downvoted or closed the same as a brand new user can ask a fantastic, well researched question.

In the end it comes down to how you want to contribute to Stack Overflow. Some people want to ask great questions, some want to answer questions with great answers, some want to monitor meta and review queues. All of those things are fine and all are needed to continue to grow Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12):

## The kinds of questions I *need* to ask aren't the kinds of questions people *want* to answer.

### That doesn't mean my questions are off-topic, either.

I've [only had one poorly received question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto?tab=questions) (which I'll get to in a moment), but by and large I've noticed a trend:  the kinds of questions that I actually do need help with aren't the kinds of questions the general populace is equipped (or patient enough) to answer.  More often than not I've had to cajole the system or wait until a guru arrived to help me solve my problem.

I'll quantify this with also admitting to falling into this trap; I tend to stick to what I know or what I understand best, and it's likely the case that I need to branch out into deeper things with Guice and Spring and JPA and the like so that I too can help others with those issues.  But I've gotta use 'em more often.

---

I'll try to keep your main themes in mind while I describe my experiences with asking questions.

- Do you feel that you will lose face if you, probably an expert in some domain, ask a question that you don't know the answer to?
- Do you feel that question reception is capricious or unfair?
- Do you think you will face easy recrimination or revenge from users whose posts you or others have criticized, downvoted, and closed in the past?
- Do you feel that it will simply take too long for you to write up a question that is considered "good"?
- Do you just always know what you need to know (because of experience or you know how to research or read documentation) without asking someone else, so you don't see the point in asking?

[Let's start with my most recent question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42635091/1079354)  I had ***genuinely*** reached the end of my rope here, and I had nowhere else to turn to.  I had no insight into what could be causing my issue, since every guide I had read suggested that this "just works".  I had no way of diagnosing this since this particular Git issue isn't one that one would normally expect "verbose" output for.

And yet, I asked.  It took me a while to actually string together the words I needed, but I asked.  I had to wordsmith it just right to make it crystal clear what it was I was looking for.  I had to be sure that there could be **no ambiguity** in what my problem was.  Then, I posted my question.

...and you know what I was rewarded with for my efforts? A sardonic remark:  "works on my box."

Wow, wonderful!  That was really insightful.  That answer couldn't have been more enlightening, and....yeah, you get the picture.  If I were a first-time Stack Overflow user, I'd just leave and never bother coming back.  Why would I bother any further if I am faced with a genuine problem, yet get such backlash?  I don't need this in my life.

Fortunately, having been around this community for so long, and having seen both sides of this play out, I stuck it out.  One part because I didn't think that one snide remark warranted "cutting my nose to spite my face" as it were.  One part because I knew that a true Git guru walked amongst this site.  Sure enough, not only did they answer, they genuinely *solved* my problem, and I walked away with a deeper understanding.

My big takeaways here:

- I didn't really care if I lost face.  A man needs to know when to admit they're stumped, and I've never lost respect for a person whose admitted to *not* knowing something.
- The reception to this question initially felt openly hostile.  The thing is, I've [written *copious* amounts of Meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1079354+improve+question) on helping others improve their questions, or ways for them to improve their questions, but...there are times when I genuinely think that shouting at a wall is more constructive.
- I'm not bothered with revenge.  They can take all the downvote pot-shots they like.  Script'll catch them.
- The ramp-up time for asking questions is definitely high, but I find that as my tolerance for the pain caused by the issue approaches zero, the surplus of time I have to write a good question approaches infinity.  That said, I think I was also fortunate; I do have a way with words and have largely dodged any negative impressions from my questions.
- I've never heard of this "savant" you speak of.  I doubt anyone has *ever* just "known everything" here.  I'm certainly not this person.  I admit though, if I don't know something I'll look it up.  On occasion I'll share it with the world if I deem it appropriate.  Otherwise, I'll ask when I need to.

---

Right.  Let me get to [a less-well-received question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533816/1079354).  This is actually one I'm hard stuck on, because:

- I don't work for the company that does this project anymore,
- That project is <s>thankfully</s> scrapped, and
- I don't work in this technology stack anymore.

But it's stuck at a negative value, and I don't have that many questions, y'know; it'd be pretty damn embarrassing if I were to get a question ban over *that* one.  Heck, that question's even been deleted by the system at one point.  I just don't have ***any*** good way to fix it.

My big problem with this was, I needed to appeal to two different groups of developers: those working in the React space, and those working in the Rails space.  Getting one-sided answers from either of them would be bad, and it wasn't like I could actually provide code; it was very much the case that I had a working solution but simply wanted to know if Rails could be done the way that I was asking it to be.  Effectively, I was trying to recreate a SPA in Rails, which sounds silly to me now, and likely sounds silly to anyone else.

However, I don't think I did a poor job with my question.  I admit watching it like a hawk, and after receiving a React-centric response (shoot), I noted that it wouldn't work well for me and received a downvote *not that long afterwards*.  I doubt it was a coincidence.

---

I'll end by answering your follow-up questions as well.

> ...[H]ow can we improve question reception for established users?

I don't know.  I don't think there's a good answer to this.  I don't think there's a real solution to this.  It's tough to say what question will be received well or what question won't be.  It's like rolling a 20-sided die and expecting to land on a 20 every time.

> Do we need a privilege that makes downvotes cost the voter on questions? (Like for every 10k rep you get to ask 1 "privileged" question per month.)

That wouldn't really solve a problem.   It'd put a tax on users for downvoting high-rep users.  Let me tell you, I've seen some absolute *stinkers* come from 20K+ users.  I don't see a reason for the system to punish me for ***doing what the system told me to do***.

> Or do we just need to improve our culture of welcoming questions from established users?

Let's do this.  See you in about five years?  /pessimism

In all frankness I'm trying to do this effort.  My biggest concern is that this is all theatre.

> It would be a great boon to all of us to have a new population of really smart and experienced users asking questions here, right?

Eh.  It's the bikeshed principle; if we're talking about the nuclear reactor again, we'll just hear the crickets.

> If you're reading this, you're probably really smart and part of that ideal population, but are you afraid to ask?

Not afraid, no.  Just...irritated.  Disillusioned.

It's easier to answer a question than it is to ask one.  It's easier to criticize or give feedback in *either* direction than to receive it.  It's easier to solve a problem than to *admit* that one has a problem.  Worse, it's no fun knowing that there are actual groups of people that intentionally go around, deleting questions which they think are poor, *and think they're doing a good service by doing so*, when those questions don't really need to be deleted at all.  And if you *really* want to know more about that, then don't hesitate to use your moderator powers to reach out.

Comment: You're saying that a group of people are deleting good questions, but in order to delete a question it first need to be closed, plus the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on a question - So for deleting a standard question, a minimum of 5 individuals are required to cast their close/delete vote. Do you think this number should be increased then? Do you believe it is a large scale problem?

Comment: The less-well-received example is funny. The answer explains to use the flux pattern and uses React as an example (granted that is a common place to see the pattern implemented), which you apparently misunderstood as that you were recommended to use React ;)

Comment: @AlonEitan:  I speak of the SOCVR, which I've been critical of in the past.  I've had chats with a few key members which have led me to believe that securing the close votes for a question that they're not fond of isn't a difficult feat.  From there, deletion only naturally follows.

Comment: @Gimby:  *You* tell me of an example of the flux pattern that *doesn't* make use of JavaScript or React (and yes I know those overlap) that existed before I asked that question, and I'll retract that part of my answer.  This is what I'm talking about; I was given a pattern that I couldn't realistically apply to my specific domain, and I'm expected to know how it works to apply it to *other* domains?  The kind of React I was doing existed *before* Flux was a thing, too.

Comment: @Makoto I'm a member in that room, which is very strict and sensitive when it come to reporting and closing questions - You must specify a valid reason, you don't allow to target users and senior members remind other not to make a ligh decisions ([example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=37442859#37442859)), so I can only hope that you're wrong about the negative effect this room create - I want to belive its members don't act as a gang

Comment: @AlonEitan:  At one point, I did too.  But I'm less convinced of it nowadays.  I do believe that it acts with the best of intentions, but even then the road to Hell is paved with those.

Answer (score 11):

My main reason for not asking questions: It seems that it will take a long time to produce a question of sufficient quality and that that time could be better spent researching the problem and experimenting myself.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually fair, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I am not saying that this is a bad system.

Comment: Is not the research and experimentation you do to find the answer the *exact same* research and experimentation you'd do to ask a quality question?  What research and experimentation would you do to ask a quality question that you wouldn't *also* do to find the answer yourself?  This is all of course  by design; the question quality guidelines exist, at least in part, to encourage people to do the work that they're able to do themselves to find the answer, before resorting to consuming other people's time to get an answer.

Comment: @Servy: The difference I've found myself is that recording every step in troubleshooting is rather laborious, and it's much faster to simply keep in mind what I've learned as I learn it, saving only a few pointers to things I might have trouble remembering as the process goes on. But a question *must* record everything at all relevant, or it's useless. So writing up a question can take a lot longer than simply running through it myself, because I have to keep breaking my flow in order to compose a coherent explanation for any old random person to understand.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The only reason to ask on SO in the first place is because you've *already* done the research and experimentation *and not been able to find an answer*.  At which point you will need to spend some time writing up what you've done, found, and crafting an understandable question around that (and that *does* take time).  But the time spent asking the question isn't time spent researching/experimenting; you already did that before even deciding to ask a question on SO, and it's not time you *could* be spent researching/experimenting, *because you already did as much as you could do*.

Comment: @Servy: And at that point, just how much do I *really* need an answer that I quite possibly won't get anyway in any kind of reasonable time? Enough to re-spend a decent fraction of the time and effort I spent on research writing it up? No.

Answer (score 8):

I have three main reasons, and I don't see any of them on your list. Maybe #3 is.

In order of frequency:

#### 1. The question I have is already answered.

Maybe it took a while to find, but I was able to find an existing answer on the site. Sometimes I get it directly from Google Search, and sometimes I have to jump through the related links several times, but the information is there. No point in asking again.

#### 2. The question I have can't really be answered by people on the site.

I work at a large company and we have a lot of internal tools or additional constraints that make the common solutions to certain problems unfeasible. For example, we use a language that's similar to SQL, but has some variations, but I don't believe the language is publicly available.  So if I have a problem and the common SQL solution won't work, I'm better off asking people inside the company than on Stack Overflow.

#### 3. I get tired arguing about the question.

There are a few occasions where I've been able to find a generally answerable question and what I believe is a minimal example to illustrate it, but of course in the real world I have all kinds of business constraints. When relevant, I summarize the important ones just so I don't invite answers I can't use, but this often provokes "oh, you have an X/Y" problem or "justify why you're doing this".

I'll attempt to clarify the first few times, but after a while I'm spending more time justifying business decisions not under my control or that don't really relate to the question, and I end up without a solution to my problem, which deters asking again in the future.

Comment: In addition to Dan's point, understanding why a given constraint exists is often highly relevant to understanding what the appropriate solution to a problem is.  Using your own example, if you ask a SQL question but just say, "but I can't use the `Foo` keyword" without explaining why, it's much harder to help you than saying, "I'm using a database with a proprietary SQL variation that doesn't support the `Foo` keyword," which may prompt people to ask what other features it does/doesn't support, helping them better answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty simple, really. The expectation among MSO regulars is usually that [the asker will have *exhausted* their own resources before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593). Since a typical skilled answerer has a lot more resources, their question may well not be worth putting that much effort into it, and by the time they have run out of things to try, going back through all their research and reorganizing it to be concise and understandable can be a major hassle. And the question itself will of course likely be complex and difficult to handle, so answers are less likely to come in quickly, or in some cases at all.

So it's mostly a problem of *double standards*. Lazy askers, of which there are millions, can ask simple low-effort questions fairly freely, and despite our distaste for them, they cannot be reliably blocked and often get answered, even quite quickly. Worse yet, these are arguably *useful* to other askers too lazy to even ask — in other words, web searchers, the site's notional audience. But anyone with a high rep, especially from answering, is going to need to work much harder to get the same reception. At that point, why even ask the question unless it's absolutely mission-critical?

When the cost of questions is much higher and the value distribution stays pretty similar, the simplest economic theory will tell you what happens.

The answer to [Should we be afraid to ask questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/should-we-be-afraid-to-ask-questions) was overwhelmingly **YES**. This hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't ask questions anymore because... I can generally figure out the problem in far less time than it would take for me to write up the question. (#5)

I don't see a point in self answer questions either. I mean, yeah, share knowledge and all, but... if you can solve it, so can anyone else... why does it need to be posted? If someone else reaches said problem and cant solve it, it's not really a problem with the, eh, problem, it's a problem related to said user's ability to research/debug... which covers the majority of the questions asked on SO. And yet, so many of the answers completely skip this topic! They just provide a working solution and move on, not explaining what the user was doing wrong or why they got in that situation or how to avoid getting back into that situation in the future. It's just not useful. If you're going to answer a question, solve the underlying problem of how to properly debug/research the problem, not just the presented problem. (I'm also guilty of this.)

Comment: I feel like there would be more answers addressing the underlying issues that cause low quality posts to keep occurring if people weren't so darn obsessed with rep farming by being the FGITW. I think the fact that people want to just solve the problem faster than anyone else to get the points cuts into the incentive to address underlying issues like you said.

Comment: I agree, though... i don't know what we could possibly do that would solve that. It's not just about the rep points, it's also that feel good feeling of helping someone. Points can be adjusted, but that feeling of accomplishment cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

I ask questions when I am stuck, have googled a fair bit, tried some things and have hit a dead end.

But now I know that a question will get shot down in flames if there is anyway any part of it can be interpreted as poor, lazy, not researched,... Didnt used to happen

I do know that the question is clear in my mind (I have all the context) and that I forget that the SO readers only see what I typed (they cant see inside my head). But please comment 'please clarify the what platform u are on' , 'did you try fizzling yr boggle', etc. rather than just saying 'Closed off topic', 'did you bother to do ANY research',...

I try to follow those rules when answering, but I will certainly shoot down sheer laziness (direct posting of the text of a class assignment for example)

Comment: I see dozens of questions of appalling quality every day. My choices are (i) allocate some of my spare time to the user and guide them, (ii) use the moderation tools as intended, (iii) do nothing. I need to be in a good mood to do (i) and I believe I should do (ii) instead of (iii).

Answer (score 2):

I don't ask questions because most of the time I know the *language* in and out, but it's a *library* or some other dependency that I'm having problems with - and it's usually the result of a bug.

Bigger libraries that would be "on topic" for SO generally have great docs and a plethora of good Q/A on SO already. It's the small, lesser maintained dependencies that require me to consult on Github or other bug trackers/mailing lists.

---

I think we've reached a point where a lot of the general questions have been asked and answered in a variety of ways an number of times.

Answer (score 1):

I can generally find a good-enough workaround such that **I don't really need an answer**.  Given the effort required to write a good question and defend it (against both reasonable and unreasonable comments), it just isn't worth asking.

For example, recently I was working in C++ with a class template `template<unsigned int N> class Foo`, whose instances all derive from `FooBase` (for members that don't depend on `N`).  I wanted to write a variadic function template that can take any sequence of `FooBase&` and `Foo<N>&` (there can be more than one, but their `N` must be the same) and return `Foo<N>`.  I eventually came up with something based on `constexpr` functions with `if constexpr`, but it seems really weird and unnatural, and I'm pretty sure it isn't the idiomatic way to do this.  Still, it works (I have tests) and that's good enough for me to move on with my actual work.

I'm not inclined to write this one up as a self-answer given that I only find it good enough, especially given the unusually high bar for self-answered questions, and that I'm not a regular in [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

I do have a couple of questions that might be worth self-answering, and that I am more confident in the answers to, but they're algorithm-level concepts that I expect to get a bad reception here.  I'd prefer to revive my blog and post them there.

Answer (score 1):

I recently set up a slightly old implementation. It was a SimpleMembership Authorization and Authentication provider using a MSSQL Database with the ASP.Net schema.

Since this is nothing fancy, and nothing new, there was a lot of coverage. The whole process went without a hitch, and the small issues where I had a question about something were already asked and answered at Stack Overflow.

This is generally how all of my quandaries go.

- Me: Hm, that's odd.
- *google oddity*
- *read Stack Overflow answer*
- move on.

**This is why I started contributing to Stack Overflow.** So that I could give back. As a resource it is invaluable because of the amount of time it saves me figuring out nuance.

Now that the site has grown significantly, the amount of coverage it has is immense, amazing, unbelievabru. Everyone who develops software loves the content here, even if some disagree with its strictness.

This is not to say I haven't asked questions.

[image]

However, recently, more and more, the questions I would have are already answered, and the answers are high quality.