# Two B or not two B - Farewell, BoltClock and Bhargav!

Tags: discussion, moderators, announcement, moderator-resignation

On November 22nd and 23rd, 2021 we celebrated two big anniversaries - a 10 year moderator tenure for BoltClock on the 23rd and a 5 year tenure for Bhargav Rao. In their ways, these two have done an immense service to this site and I'm honored they've spent so much time helping us out and responding to the needs of Stack Overflow.

Considering this, I'm sad to announce that **they're both stepping down as moderators.** While they won't have diamonds as of later today, they've both assured me that they won't completely disappear on us all, so we hope to see them around in some capacity - but I certainly wish them well and some deserved time off from SO.

### BoltClock

[image: BoltClock]

BoltClock was elected in the [second Stack Overflow election, in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2) and was awarded their diamond on November 23rd at 00:13 UTC. Over the course of their ten years as a moderator, they've done much to keep this site clean through thousands of edits (a top 50 all-time editor) and supporting other community members on meta (over 1000 answers including MSE). This has shown them to be an expert who is willing to share that expertise with others... and that's in addition to their nearly 6k answers on SO itself.

Their ability to clearly talk through interpersonal interactions on SE while keeping things light and recognizing the human behind the screen is something we should all try to emulate. This is integral to helping the community here understand how to successfully communicate and use the platform effectively. On top of that, they've frequently stood up when they thought something needed to change particularly in relation to whether that was an incorrectly-closed post or helping to handle rudeness.

BoltClock, while I didn't know you when you were first elected, I have come to know you since and recognize you to be an excellent moderator - one I think many of the other moderators look up to. It seems like you came in with big plans - know that whether or not those plans were realized, your impact here has been large and appreciated.

### Bhargav Rao

[image: Bhargav Rao]

Bhargav was elected in the [eighth Stack Overflow election, in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8) and was awarded his diamond four minutes after the voting phase ended, on November 22nd at 20:04 UTC. Bhargav was recently recognized for reaching a grand total of [over 500k flags handled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411441/congrats-to-bhargav-rao-on-500k-handled-flags). This is an impressive feat and well-worthy of recognition and, well... a vacation.

In addition to handling flags, he also spent much of his time here on meta doing tag clean-ups - many of the tag burnination and synonymization requests were led by him. This can't be understated, either - SO is huge and many of these burninations involved thousands of posts that needed review and retagging.

Bhargav, as much as I know the team here has appreciated your efforts over your five years as a moderator - you deserve some time where you don't feel like you have to handle hundreds of flags per day so I hope you enjoy your "retirement". The amount of knowledge you've been willing to share with other moderators is admirable - I let you get first place in rep on the Mod Team but be sure I'll take over the lead again shortly. ;)

---

To you both - I can't possibly express the gratitude for anyone other than myself and on behalf of Stack Overflow (the company) - but I know that so many others appreciate and have benefitted from your efforts over the years, whether they know you personally or not. You both embody something that I feel is so wonderful about this site and why I have stayed here and continue to work for the community - you want to make this platform the best it can be and you give so much of yourselves and your time to shape it as best as you can.

This is something we can never repay but know that you have our gratitude and I'm sure many others from the community will express their own when they hear you're stepping down.

Thank you both so much.

Comment: [B](https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/28240)

Comment: This isn't forever, right? You will come back at some point, I hope. Right?

Comment: Blimey, I joined SO after BoltClock was elected so they've been ever-present to me. I did vote for Bhargav though. I'm sad to see them both step down but completely understand. Thanks for everything both of you.

Comment: Oh my... That's an extra 100k flags a year for the rest of the mods to handle! Is this the reason for the recent elections, or should we expect another one soon?

Comment: I hate this news but have an upvote for the title.

Comment: @DavidG that is such a surreal sentence to read

Comment: @BoltClock Surreal that you are omnipresent? ;)

Comment: So many upvotes on this question... I guess everyone's happy to see them go!

Comment: Next election: 32 moderator positions available to fill the gap

Comment: Now Brad Larson is the oldest mod.

Comment: @peterh He is if you forget Michael Myers. :D If you remember Michael, he was and still is the longest-serving mod.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to upvote this because I'm grateful to them for their service to the site or downvote because I don't want them to step down.

Comment: BoltClock has the distinction of being the #1 all time user in Singapore.  They will hopefully still be a major content contributor after stepping down from moderation.

Comment: Hum, mini-Bad News then, my Nb #2 + #3 Mods, (#1 being #Cody)... Good luck further you both, and Thanks for your tremendous Input...! (My Upvote on the Thread/Qt means I'm "sad" to see them step down...)

Comment: Just wondering now: We just had a "big Circus" electing +2 New Mods, => were those +2 New Mods "in Preparation" of B+B departing...?, or do we soon get some Election again to replace them...?

Comment: Thank you both for your long periods of excellent service. You have my admiration and gratitude, and that of many others. Good luck to you both with whatever you are up to now.

Comment: @chivracq The last moderator election was conducted with the knowledge that some of the current moderators would be resigning shortly afterward. We will definitely not have another election (there must be at least 6 months in-between elections). It is *possible* that we might call up the runner-up from the last election, if both the moderator team and staff agree that it is necessary, but I wouldn't count on that happening. Also... I hardly think that it's fair or polite to call the election a "big circus". Elections are always interesting, and never drama-free, but overall, all went well.

Comment: @Cody, OK, Thanks for Reply, then hum, could have opened 3 or 4 Positions then, ah-ah...! This could have been mentioned "at that time"..., (or maybe it was but I missed it...), and "big Circus" meant as an (aside) semi-Joke, it was impossible to "miss the Election" from all Notifs and Popups and featured Threads everywhere, and all related Discussions, then yep-yep, I meant "interesting" (Elections) then...

Comment: @chivracq Generally, even when the need is great, we prefer not to elect too many mods at once. It takes some time to train the new mods and get them up to speed. See, e.g., [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398358) from back in 2020. Yeah, the notifications about the election are intentional. We *do* want to make sure that no one can miss them. We've had many people complain in the past about having missed the notifications about an election, even [asking for notifications in advance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409301).

Comment: @Cody, yep, I understand..., and "one day" pretty soon, we'll have 1 Human Mod (maybe 2), and 1 AI/Bot-Mod... Pb solved, ah-ah...!

Comment: @BoltClock I was wondering if the OP Was a B reference when I saw you :D Was great to see the comment. I remember when I joined SO it was nice to see people from Newgrounds (the clock reference was immediate). 10 years is quite a bit of time to moderate. Good job!

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum hi and thanks!

Comment: @BoltClock Cheers!  Can't believe it's been 10 years.  Time really flies.  Good luck in new adventures.

Comment: Thank you, @BoltClock for being a voice of calm and reason. You set an admirable example to other moderators and all users. All the very best.

Comment: aww thank you @Rounin!

Comment: TBH, the main reason I've spotted @BoltClock at all is the Applebloom avatar they replaced only recently. And, well, the frequency of encountering it clearly highlights their selfless activity, especially in editing ;)

Comment: That title is [too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzi-azI7PIE&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=10&t=7m45s) [clever](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Shakespearean#Adjective)... I had to use [defocused temporal perception](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHG2tHJWVK8&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&index=7&t=11m34s) to get it.

Answer (score 208):

Thank you all.

5 years ago, as I accepted this position as a moderator I was a young and nervous small boy and today as I step out of this place, I've learned a lot and grown into a more mature human being. I want to thank you all for the enormous support that you've shared over the past few years, and for all the help throughout. Stack Overflow, as a community, has been through many rough times and the fact that we are all here together is a testament to the amount of love and respect we have for each other.

Stack Overflow has been an integral part of my life. It has been there with me when I was an undergrad, during my job, my masters, when I moved cities, countries, and so on. So the decision to step down as a mod was a very hard and difficult one to take.

My public moderator activity, be it related to tags or chat, was slightly on the decline over the past year, and I did not want to drag myself on in a position where I could not stand up to the promises I made in my election. Adding to that, the current set of moderators have been really good at handling the load, and have ramped up really quickly, which made me realize that this is a good time to part ways.

There have been changes to my personal life as well, I'm switching cities soon and have a ton of other work which I would need to divert my attention to, so I cannot do justice to my service as a moderator here. Finally, 500k flags and 5 years is a nice round figure to call it a day.

I still recall asking Shog, 3 minutes after entering the moderator room if I could start handling flags then and there, and then realizing that there were 500 NAA flags in the queue. Clearing the flag queue completely was a great pastime of mine, and I will certainly miss it in the future. The tag cleanup and burnination efforts which was spearheaded by the community was another thing that I enjoyed immensely. We did share an emotional bond here, on Meta, which I will miss the most.

All that said, I would like to also apologize to you all for any mistakes that I've committed, and I will certainly wear the paper bag for those. Handling flags is a daunting task and I did have my fair share of errors while doing the same. I would like to thank you all again for forgiving me for those, and I hope I did well to represent you all.

For the question about whether I would be back as a moderator or not, I'm not sure. They say never say never, but will I be back in the near future, I don't think so. I am planning to stay active in chat ([SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics)), where you can drop by to ask any questions to me. (You can also find me on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/BhargavHS)).

Finally, I would thank you all a third time, and frankly I can't thank you all enough. Cheers to you all, and hope you all achieve your highest desires!

Comment: ***S M O L B O I***

Comment: I'm yoinking that brown paper bag you don't need it anymore, fly, be free

Comment: You have been a great mod! THANKS BR!, for everything you done with immense effort.

Comment: It seems your thrice incantation also stopped working :) Thanks for all the service you've done! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster. Yep, I stopped following chat transcripts around a week back to prep myself for retiring. You can always invite me over. :)

Comment: I am going to quote a personal favorite cult classic video game from the 90's called the 7th Guest: COME BAAAAAAAAAAAAACK!

Comment: [Crosslinking from 2019 Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329687/tag-synonym-dashboard-2-0/329701#comment1075713_329701): "@AdamLear I support _whatever Bhargav wants_ when it comes to tag management. He found and approved an obvious synonym request in a tag that no one has the tag-rep to do, _4 years_ after I asked for it."

Comment: Thanks so much @Michael. I still recall that comment and remember how it helped to drive my point home. So thanks again! :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. While so much on this site has generated negative feelings, you've always been a positive influence.  I'm glad for you that you are now moving on, hopefully to better things.  Everyone who uses this site has benefited from your work, and I wish you every success in your future career.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @user1725145 :)

Comment: OMG! Why? Why did my two best mods / friends stepped down? @BoltClock and Bhargav, you both rock. Come back soon as mods! :)

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, I'll definitely think about coming back once I find out that I have enough time for this. :)

Comment: Yayy! Thanks @BhargavRao! 

Answer (score 153):

Five years is a heck of a run. Ten years...

### BoltClock

Lemme paint a picture: when BoltClock joined the team, the moderator team on Stack Overflow was completely overwhelmed. There was no review system as we know it today; EVERYTHING went into the queue, and employees routinely had to jump in just to keep the backlog at... Well, at a dauntingly overwhelming level. While new mods on other sites were encouraged to take time and carefully consider each flag, new mods on SO were encouraged to handle them as fast as possible (or... Maybe just a little bit faster than that).

This inevitably led to some fatigue, to mistakes, or simply to situations in which moderators were making SO MANY decisions in a day that even a superhumanly-low error rate still led to a constant stream of [nasty callouts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network).

And this was the role that young BoltClock took on. The challenge he faced, and faced down, with persistence and drive.

But that's not all. BoltClock has been an inspiration to other moderators right from the start - willing to call out problems with The Way Things Are Done or The Way Things Are Talked About even when doing so meant standing alone. A regular here on meta (originally on MetaSE), and an irregular regular in the Teachers' Lounge, he was an early advocate for the unique challenges and needs of moderation on very active sites at a time when conversations among moderators too often drifted into "perfect vs. good" territory.

This all must have taken its toll, both in terms of time spent and emotional energy expended. Which makes such a tenure all the more impressive.

We didn't always agree, and I'm afraid that our communication styles clashed far more often than I would've liked... But I consider myself privileged to have been able to work with BoltClock for a large portion of that decade.

Best of luck in all your future work!

### Bhargav

I'll always remember Bhargav from a particular conversation about the flag UI, in which he noted that most of the time he spent handling flags was on his phone during his walk to work. That spoke to two things that I think we too often overlooked:

1. This is a *volunteer* role - folks slot it in when they have the time to spare, not when we demand it.
2. Sitting at a desktop to do rote tasks is... A somewhat archaic mode of interaction.

Bhargav altered the role to suit his abilities and skills, building or adapting tools and processes as needed along the way. And he did so with grace and an enthusiasm that was a constant inspiration to others - both curators and moderators.

More than a few times he had to stop employees to remind them that the tools they were modifying weren't for their own use, but meant for folks who used the site daily - and that however well-intentioned their efforts might've been, *they were breaking those workflows.* This too must've been wearying, but I cannot recall a time when Bhargav was anything short of patient and polite, nor anything less than firm and clear in his communication.

### Moderators as examples for the rest of us

It is fitting, I think, that these two choose to retire together: their common trait is the example that they set, year in and year out, for us to learn from. They may be hanging up their metaphorical hats, but their examples remain - and we would be fools to not continue to learn from them!

Comment: Thanks for everything, Shog. The amount of support that you shared over the years was immeasurable. The burnination efforts which Cat mentions wouldn't have been possible without you. :)

Comment: Thank you Shog, as usual a way with words. I didn't realize we clashed all that much... you only gave me like two or three talkings-to, and most of my discontent in general was directed at others or at the state of affairs. But you're right that I was highly vocal and opinionated, for better or for worse (I really like how Catija put it, particularly in the last sentence about me).

Comment: Well, the workflow-breaking hasn't stopped, and now our tireless fountain of patience has been turned off. Looks like I'll have to try my best at patience and politeness. We're *really* rolling the dice now.

Comment: "*More than a few times he had to stop employees to remind them that the tools they were modifying weren't for their own use, but meant for folks who used the site daily - and that however well-intentioned their efforts might've been, they were breaking those workflows.*" Bhargav's certainly a saint for that. Better than what we deserved.

Comment: As usual, Shog9 puts it better than I could. After working with someone as a volunteer janitor for nearly a decade, all I can think about is how fun it was to chat with BoltClock that whole time. I learned so much from our discussions over the years. Bhargav has been a beacon of optimism, while handling an unbelievable volume of thankless tasks. I'm going to miss tracking down weird problems with him. The biggest upside to being a moderator has always been the people you get to work with, and I'm sure glad I got a chance to do so with BoltClock and Bhargav.

Answer (score 108):

For those who don't understand [my comment on the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413240/two-b-or-not-two-b-farewell-boltclock-and-bhargav/413263#comment880741_413240), the "B" in the title is a reference to the 2001 Newgrounds submission [B](https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/28240) that catalyzed the formation of the Clock Crew, which is where my persona [comes from](https://boltclock.newgrounds.com). I know some of my fellow Clocks will be reading this, so don't be coy!

I wonder if any of the 119 people who upvoted [this comment I posted in 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites#comment730723_389906) remembers it, because hoo boy did it age poorly in more ways than one:

> As the person who will become the oldest elected moderator on Stack Overflow after Robert steps down, and as someone who has just been back on the site a full month as of today after vanishing for 5, I'll be issuing a statement of my own soon (and I may not necessarily even do it on Meta). For now, I'd like to focus on some side projects I'm excited about for the coming week or so, and I've sent Robert my utmost regards in private.

First, those side projects took *way* more than a week to come to fruition. More importantly, the statement I promised never materialized here *nor* on my blog in the years since. (I also have a few maintenance-related loose ends on meta I never tied up and I regret having to let go.) It feels a little mismatched for me to deliver the statement only when I'm actually stepping down now, as I only made the decision to do so earlier this year, so it's not completely connected. Take this post then as not directly fulfilling that promise, but rather a new statement in its stead.

---

It was thanks to James Gifford (whom some of you might know from Ask Ubuntu) that I stepped up and nominated myself in 2011, ten years ago. I was 19, and it was the roughest year of my life by far — 2020 and 2021 couldn't compare. Stack Overflow was a safe space for me, where I could continue doing what I do best: disseminating my knowledge and expertise of technologies I care about. Running for moderator was the logical next step for me, and to have the community as well as folks I've looked up to back me up has been such an honor, as is being the largest Singapore-based contributor to the site by far.

As they say, "when you're at rock bottom the only way you can go is up," and my life has definitely been gradually looking up over the course of my 20s. I don't credit Stack alone for it — there were a few life-changing events which all had a greater impact but Stack remained a safe space for me, and honestly my 10-year tenure has been surprisingly free of drama. Literally the only thing I remember is the [teen moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network) situation that Shog and Cody have alluded to before me — I wasn't online when it happened and I only found out the *next day*, I think. By then, *everyone* had jumped to my defense, so all I had left to do was laugh off the absurdity of it all. Other than that, I'm really grateful that my presence has been cherished on here. It's surreal to even hear from people who weren't around before I became a moderator, speaking about my presence and status as something that's just always been a given for them.

Then the welcoming wagon situation happened. Things happened with the company. I don't have to get into specifics; I think it's safe to say that the shake-up has affected all of us in one way or another, and I was no exception — my activity plummeted after that, and honestly I don't know if many people noticed or if most people assumed I was just quietly working behind the scenes all this time (I wasn't, really — unlike Bhargav and the rest, I was one of the mods who *didn't* spend most of their time in the flag queue).

However, it definitely opened my eyes to what some people go through not only here, but in the industry. That this site has been a safe space for me to comfortably share my knowledge and keep things in order was really a privilege I enjoyed none the wiser; but even so, during my tenure itself before any of that happened, I'd also grown aware of some behaviors of my own and others that rubbed me the wrong way. I thought of myself lightheartedly as embodying the "angry moderator" trope from time to time, but I definitely worked hard over the years to unlearn some of my own toxicity, and [learn to interact with others better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367976/are-we-collectively-wired-to-be-rude/367987#367987).

Ironically, this had little to do with my moderator role — it was more about how I reacted to dubious or exasperating questions, answers and comments. [Here's an example from as recently as 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue/6433475#comment72250420_6433475) because I was fed up with all the complaints about a subtle (but well-documented) CSS gotcha. In at least the following two years others have appropriately called me on it and I do see how my comment was unnecessarily callous, regardless of the aforementioned complaints. I guess the occasional slip-up is understandable...

In any case, being a moderator and witnessing first-hand the myriad positive and negative interpersonal interactions on the site, has absolutely helped me grow in this area. While the welcoming situation has been an enormous change of pace and atmosphere for most people including myself, I was one of those who really supported the initiative, except like the rest I just disagreed with some of its execution. One feature that I vehemently supported, though, was the new contributor indicator; I really wanted to explain why it's important, why it's helpful and how we as experienced users were supposed to work with it and adapt to it, but I never found the words or energy for a proper write-up.

Meanwhile, Catija's and Shog's descriptions have been delightfully validating, and I really appreciate them taking the time:

> [BoltClock's] ability to clearly talk through interpersonal interactions on SE while keeping things light and recognizing the human behind the screen is something we should all try to emulate. This is integral to helping the community here understand how to successfully communicate and use the platform effectively. On top of that, they've frequently stood up when they thought something needed to change particularly in relation to whether that was an incorrectly-closed post or helping to handle rudeness.

> ... It seems like you came in with big plans - know that whether or not those plans were realized, your impact here has been large and appreciated.

> ... BoltClock has been an inspiration to other moderators right from the start - willing to call out problems with The Way Things Are Done or The Way Things Are Talked About even when doing so meant standing alone.

Since Bhargav's final moderator statistics have been published, I guess I'll share my own, courtesy of Catija herself:

[image: I've handled 30,228 flags, deleted 7.3k comments and 12k posts, closed 7.1k posts, made 18.4k edits, issued 546 moderator messages, asked 19 and answered 552 meta questions, posted 5.3k meta comments, cast 13k upvotes and 2.5k downvotes, and created 6k posts and 35.6k comments]

30,228 flags handled in 10 years. I distinctly remember handling at least 100 flags on my first day. Like many others, I hit the ground running, but I quickly decided that the queue wasn't for me, so 30,000 in 10 doesn't quite amount to 3000 a year — it's much tighter than that. Either way, I'm happy to have helped however I can. Many of you will have found tremendously more value in my contributions to meta and my handling of situations outside the flag queue, by comparison.

Speaking of contributions, my contributions in [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) opened up opportunities with Microsoft which you can read about in my [Internet Explorer tribute](https://blog.novalistic.com/archives/2016/01/a-tribute-to-internet-explorer). Eventually in 2017 I was promoted to [Microsoft MVP](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/5002751), though ultimately I stepped down from that program as well, in 2020, for the same personal reasons that I've made the decision to step down as a moderator.

And it was thanks to Stack Overflow that I found my [specialty](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-selectors/topusers) in [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors), thanks to early answers such as these:

- [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean/3225905#3225905)
- [Select every Nth element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462298/select-every-nth-element-in-css/3462301#3462301)
- [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305)
- [CSS combinator precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851635/css-combinator-precedence/3851754#3851754)
- [What does a[href^="..."] do in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859101/what-does-ahref-do-in-css/3859189#3859189)
- [:first-child not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505686/first-child-not-working-as-expected/4505716#4505716)
- [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector/5546296#5546296)
- [How to write :hover condition for a:before and a:after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter/5777334#5777334)

followed shortly by one of my greatest hits of all time:

- [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107)

And just over a year ago, the transition to online meetings opened up an opportunity for me to deliver my [first ever presentation on this very specialty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGC683FOIpg) (now with an unofficial [companion Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433247/what-is-the-difference-between-where-and-is/67450559#67450559)).

It's been an incredibly eventful decade, in so many ways. I know we haven't always agreed with one another, and I know I haven't even always agreed with myself sometimes. I know there have been times I've taken it out on some of you, but there have overwhelmingly been times when what mattered most to us was supporting one another and trying to be on the same page, brainstorming solutions together. I really don't mean a slight to anyone at all when I say that we're all works in progress and we can all do better by one another. I genuinely believe that. But it does require having an open mind, and a generous helping of empathy. I know words like "toxic" and "unwelcoming" get tossed about, but I know Stack Overflow can be — and has been growing — so much better than that. Believe it or not, I was once part of the problem. And yet, I'm glad to have been part of the solution in some way.

I'm glad to know that I leave Stack Overflow better than I found it, but as said I won't be completely gone; like Bhargav, I'll still drop by from time to time, to respond to notifications or see if there's an interesting new question I can answer. In fact, that's exactly what I've been doing for the past two or three years, though my 2021 and 2019 activity on meta *massively* contrast my 2020 activity for sure! This official decision mostly serves as closure, for myself if no one else.

Thank you all for 10 years. Stack Overflow has had a particularly indispensable role in my 20s coming of age. I turn 30 in just over a month in the first week of 2022 (remember when [I handled an incident for someone on my 25th birthday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340839/user-answers-a-question-of-another-user-and-asks-the-same-question-again-already/340843#340843)? Or when [Bill the Lizard clocked in his 2048th consecutive day on my 23rd birthday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-4444-days-4444-consecutive-in-their-profile/122989#122989)? Good times), and I honest to God don't know what lies ahead of me yet and I'm a little anxious to find out in the coming years. Having said that, there's no denying Stack Overflow will continue to be a part of my life in some fashion for as long as I continue to be a developer and a champion of web standards.

I wish everyone all the best in what you do. And while today's Stack Overflow is a somewhat different place than it was a decade ago, I'm confident it'll be better for it, and I extend my warmest regards to the team, both the current team and those that came before it.

<3

Comment: Thanks to Catija for holding out until I've posted before removing my diamond. Y'know, just so I can see it under my meta post one last time.

Comment: Never you worry; I will faithfully carry on the "angry moderator" trope. :-)

Comment: So, you are no longer a unicorn?

Comment: it's raining.fullmetalalchemist.gif

Comment: They'll always be a unicorn, @Braiam. BoltClock is one of the most unique and special people that I've ever known. There are few people more deserving of the title.

Comment: I mean seriously... how many questions can you ask about CSS really? Always one more apparently.

Comment: Looks like it’s your birthday today, so happy birthday!

Comment: @Sebastian Simon: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 70):

I join Catija in expressing my gratitude (on behalf of myself and of the whole community team, and the company) and wishing you both the very best as you take some time to relax after many many years of stewardship of this community.  Thank you both for leaving it better than you found it. Take some time off to relax, and then we'll see you back here again, I know.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, you've been a great addition to the staff here and it was nice working with you and your team. :)

Comment: Hi Philippe, I believe you joined the team during my less active period so we haven't interacted much if at all. Thank you for the work you've done on the site and for the community!

Answer (score 52):

I've only had direct interactions with Bhargav Rao.

Whenever I noticed Bhargav Rao was about, I'd know all my "Not an Answer" flags would get handled in less than 1/1000 of a second.

My initial thought when I saw this announcements was **Nooooo! Please come back!**.

I will miss you as my favorite flag handler.
I wish you well. I hope this will give you time for other important things.

Comment: Thanks Scratte, you now have another person alongside you who's taking a break. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Maybe we should make a deal.. we could stop being on a break at the same time ;)

Answer (score 46):

Bhargav helped me when I was elected and took some time to train me to detect fraudsters (that's a fair return since I found out much later that I had voted for him in 2017, I had completely forgotten about that).

Like my lawnmower which could handle 400 square meters of lawn before stopping, Bhargav handled 400 flags a day for months, and it took a lot of courage and time to do so (on the good days handling 200 flags seemed harassing to me).

So, like my lawnmower, I suppose that he's a bit worn out from this thankless job and needs to get away from "the grind".

And now the queue is flooding again despite the efforts of other mods...

Thanks for the huge amount work Bhargav and also for being nice, funny and supportive!

Come back anytime, we're keeping a few <s>beers</s> flags in the freezer just in case.

Comment: Thanks! Old lawnmowers should make way for new ones. Will certainly miss the blue room. <3

Comment: then get your blades fixed and come back when it's done: )

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I drank all the beers. But there are still plenty of flags!

Answer (score 42):

Thank you BoltClock and Bhargav, both! Your service will be missed greatly. I'm glad to have gotten to know you and work with you both over the years.

To BoltClock especially, thank you for serving (intentionally or not) as a guide for so many newbies to the HTML and CSS world and the Stack Overflow world itself, including me once upon a time :-). Here's hoping your love of and evangelism for web standards stays forever as strong as your love of LEGOs and Olivia Rodrigo!

Comment: If anyone is wondering when I'll post an answer: 1) it's 2 in the morning for me, and 2) Olivia just received seven GRAMMY nominations as I write this comment, so I don't have the headspace at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for the kind words. :)

Answer (score 42):

## Two B or not two B – There is no question.

There is so much that I want to say, yet I can't seem to manage to put it into words with the eloquence I'd like. But, if I don't say something now, there won't be any better time, and the passage of time won't make it any easier.

#### BoltClock

You've been an elected moderator on Stack Overflow since, well, it seems, since forever. I remember kibitzing with you in the newly-minted Teachers' Lounge back in the day, when I was cutting my teeth moderating a small site and you were already moderating the largest site on the network. I enjoyed our conversations, and it was at this time that I developed a most profound respect for you as a person. I vividly remember [the incident that Shog9 already linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network), where someone acting like a child ironically threw a big fit about your age. I remember being very angry at this, because I already knew that, despite your age, you were one of the most level-headed and mature people on this platform. Brad's comment there sums it up about as nicely as I could ever hope to:

> Everybody's commented here, but this question bothered me enough that I had to chip in my two cents. I had seen BoltClock around the site for a good long while (well before he was elected moderator) before I found out what his age was. I have to say I was shocked, because he carried himself with greater maturity that someone twice or three times his age. I strongly endorsed him in the election because of this, and he's done a great job since then. Age plays no role here, and as far as experience goes, he's spent more time on this site than the vast majority of users.

…and that was way back in 2012. I shared those sentiments then, and I feel even more strongly about my admiration of and respect for you now. I've had the pleasure of working alongside you in recent years, even though you've been a lot less active, both in handling flags and chatting with me than I would have liked, but it's still been a great honor. I've also had the honor of watching you grow as a person and overcome obstacles in your life, which has been extremely exciting.

Catija already says it so well in the question: you have truly outstanding interpersonal skills, made all that much more impressive by your own neurodiversity. You've always been an inspiration for me, and a confirmation of the good that this platform can do. When I wrote [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342354), I had you in mind, as much as myself. I know there are still some things you disagree with in terms of how the site governs itself today. On some of those issues, we agree; on others, I see it slightly differently. That's how it's always been over the years. We've agreed on many things—indeed, always agreed on the big picture—but sometimes differed on the little things, and discussing these matters with you has always sharpened and refined my own perspective. I hope the discussions we've had over the years were equally as enlightening and enjoyable for you! I've always been hard-headed, but you've always been able to challenge me, and I appreciate it.

As I told you upon learning of your intentions to resign, you've always been one of the people who truly defined for me what it meant to be a moderator on Stack Overflow. All those years ago, you, among others like Bill the Lizard, set a standard that we are all still trying to emulate.

I'm so sorry to see you go, and I wish you would have stayed, but I understand why you've made the decision. I wish you all the best in your future pursuits. Know that you always have a home here with us, no matter how the world outside may be treating you.

#### Bhargav Rao

Bhargav is also one of the people who truly embodies, to me, what it means to be a Stack Overflow moderator. Bhargav has, since the day he was elected, always been an absolute beast in the flag queue. We all [recently celebrated your reaching the milestone of 500k handled flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411441); here's an updated screenshot from the day of your resignation:

[image: 520.9k flags handled]

This is incredible, and it speaks to your tireless dedication, which has and will continue to set an example for all of us. Over 500k flags handled, and I can count on one hand how many times I can remember you making a mistake and/or handling a flag in a way that I disagreed with. Most of the moderators have their unique specialities, but your vexillology is a continual source of awe and inspiration. And that is *in addition* to your dedicated, tireless work on burninations and retaggings.

It's a shame that you didn't see fit to stick around with us until you reached a nice round milestone like 1024k flags handled, but we were lucky that you spent the time that you did helping us out. I am going to miss you more than words can say. I trusted you and the actions that you took here on Stack Overflow *implicitly*, and…that doesn't come naturally or easily for me.

Your humility was second only to your dedication. Somehow, even while handling zillions of flags day in and day out with near-perfect accuracy, you always maintained your chill. You even found time to *document* things! This started out informally, using the feeble tools that we had available to us, such as chat bookmarks, but once the Moderator Team was launched, you quickly found that you could achieve two goals: beating Catija at the rep-race *and* sharing your knowledge for posterity's sake. While we'll never know what your *primary* motivation was, future generations of moderators will always benefit from your contributions. We won't let Catija forget!

Now, seeing your name without the diamond, it is positively surreal. It looks so wrong that I cannot even believe my eyes. Like BoltClock, but each in your own ways, you've been truly instrumental in making this place into what it is today. You've inspired me, and, I hope, all of us. I wouldn't have it any other way.

It truly sucks that you have decided to step down, and not *just* because it means that I might actually have to handle some flags! I'll miss your thoughtful perspectives and your ever-graceful way of doling out criticism. I know you're starting an exciting new chapter in your life, and I wish you all the best in that! I hope you'll stay around, continuing to help us out as you have the time available to do so.

Thank you for entrusting me to take over some of your key projects, including the "moderator" arm of the [SOBotics](https://sobotics.org/) tools. Even though I surely won't do it in exactly the same way you would have, it's a true honor that I can carry on your proud legacy. Hit me up any time. I always owe you a favor.

Comment: The padding in the header of that table is all over the place! :D

Comment: In its defense... there's a lot of information shown in that table that I didn't show, @Liam. We're just lucky that we managed to get the "all-time" stats table to load for once. Its stack normally overflows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cody, it really means a lot to me. I'm truly honored by your words. You've been an amazing addition to the mod team, and an asset since you were elected. I would miss having those long conversations with you in the blue room. Also, thanks so much for taking over the moderator only bots from SOBotics. You've provided them a nice and warm new home. And, yes, I'm looking forward to continue to contribute to the site as a normal user.

Comment: Thank you, Cody. It has been an honor getting to know you as well. I remember encountering you from time to time before I became a moderator and frankly, I'd looked up to you too. Having the opportunity to converse with you directly within TL was a real treat. I'm so glad the feeling is mutual.

Comment: Very well said; love the creative use of vexillology as well.

Answer (score 39):

Very impressive tenures by both BoltClock and Bhargav Rao. Thank you both for all you've done for the Stack Overflow community over the years. I hope you take a break to rest and relax before deciding what to do next with all your new-found free time!

Comment: Thanks Bill! I hope you can share some tips on how to have a peaceful retirement from SO modship. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao The best advice I can give is to remember that you don't have to check Meta every day anymore. :)

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I could get used to this!

Answer (score 32):

This is sad day for Stack Overflow. It is never easy to say farewell to great moderators. BoltClock and Bhargav I hope you are leaving because you have so many wonderful things going on in your lives, that you simply don't have any free time to spare cleaning the mess here. But, I also hope you will stay around.

Part of me hopes, one day you might change your mind and come back.

BoltClock, I don't think I ever directly interacted with you, but you have been here longer than I am and I have seen your name around a lot. You are one of those mods that seemed like integral part of the experience. Thank you!

Bhargav, I have no words to express how sad am I to see you step down. For me you are and you will always be the number one. I miss you already!

Comment: Thanks so much for this Dalija. We've known each other even before I became a mod. You've always been a great asset to the site in terms of flagging and reviewing. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks! You were the first mod I really knew before I casted my vote in the election. I knew I can trust you and we were always pretty much on the same page. I voted in elections before that one, but I was just wild guessing then (even though I managed to wild guess good ones) I stated to pay attention to the whole thing more after you were elected :)

Comment: Thank you Dalija. Yeah I remember coming on after a few months of inactivity and seeing you here for the first time, already a regular on meta. Pretty interesting to hear about folks who joined the site when I was just one of the mods who have always been around. Puts into perspective just how long I've been at this and how much I've established myself.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you! As a new user I gathered reputation rather quickly, and unlocked moderation powers while I was pretty much a greenhorn. So following what moderators were doing and reading their posts and reasoning on the Meta was essential for my understanding of the site, rules (why they are as they are), and at the end my participation beyond just posting questions and answers. Your dedication inspired me to help cleaning and maintaining quality, too.

Answer (score 29):

I can't say often enough that the moderators on this site have my admiration when it comes to doing their job.  Bhargav and BoltClock have done theirs well; it only took a short time in SOBotics and around Stack Overflow in general to see that.  When it comes to numbers, they're just staggering:  Bhargav has handled well over half a million flags in total.  Since he got elected in 2016, that's an average of over 275 flags every single day for 5 years, which is the kind of numerical insanity that could only come from Stack Overflow.  And BoltClock - to me it looks like things have been spread pretty evenly over moderation, editing the many, many posts on SO, and contributing their knowledge to the community.

Thanks to both of you.  Enjoy some waffles:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ollie, I do like to enjoy waffles, 'specially when they come in the keyboard shape.

Comment: Thanks, Ollie! Yeah, I've been quite the generalist.

Answer (score 25):

I've lost count of the amount of these I've seen over the last 5 years. It feels like Bhargav has personally dealt with 90% of my flags. Going to be some big shoes to fill.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Liam. I really feel appreciated by your kind words. :)

Comment: I've never been a mod (and I'm not sure I want to be!) but I'm sure it can feel lonely and un-appreciated sometimes. You are appreciated though and your hard work helped make SO better. Thanks @BhargavRao

Answer (score 12):

I'm fortunate enough to know both BoltClock and Bhargav Rao through Meta and several SO tags. BoltClock, even being a diamond moderator actively participating in [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors) questions was a huge inspiration in my early SO days. Whereas Bhargav's suggestion as a community moderator was wonderful. Both will be missed.

I completely agree with Catija. They shouldn't completely disappear on us all of a sudden.

Have a well deserved rest and do join us back.

Comment: Re *"They shouldn't completely disappear on us all of a sudden."*: This seems to be misread/misinterpreted by some. Perhaps rephrase? ([Modals are tough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT3JbwlpQxU&t=5m24s).)

Comment: Thanks, will try my best to stick around. :)

Comment: Hey there, good to hear from you and thanks for the kind words! Always an honor to see my contributions and expertise be an inspiration to others. Thanks for your contributions in the automated testing space.