# There should be an option to see the markdown of a question or answer (to learn from it)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The only way I know to see markdown is to click the Edit Button but sometimes it gives the error **Suggested edit queue is full** but for new users, it would be helpful to see the markdown directly and never get that error (I am saying to add a new button *not remove that error from the Edit Button*)

Comment: There are other reasons to want to see the markdown of someone's question as well, for instance if they have a whitespace error that is not evident in the rendered version.

Comment: Click "edit"/"improve this answer", or use "source" from the revision history.

Comment: No, revision history is always available, because there's always been at least 1 revision (the original). It isn't linked from the UI, but it's always available at: `/posts/<id>/revisions` @user16320675

Comment: The Markdown help is a much better way to learn Markdown: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: how did you do this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413240/two-b-or-not-two-b-farewell-boltclock-and-bhargav?cb=1 @cody-gray

Comment: What are you referring to? The edit that added flair? It's described in your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16714199/user16714199/flair

Comment: but you did this on boltclock and Bhargav Rao's profile if I try https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock/flair It says page not found is it that only mods can do it for others?

Comment: @user16714199 that page is only accessible by the user itself, and while mods can access anyone's flair page, the format for the image flair is the same (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/[User_ID].png`), so actually there's no need to access other's flair page to use it.